# Hiding variable input in psql

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am attempting to prompt for a username and password when running a database creation script, and I want to hide any text input for my password prompt. In Oracle's sqlplus, I can use `HIDE` at the end of the line to suppress the user's input from appearing on the screen. Is there an equivalent for PostgreSQL's psql?

Current progress:

```
\prompt 'Enter database user password: ' ss_password
```

Comment: "\password username" will do it for changing a postgres users password. Is that workable in your script?

Comment: @Phil - It looks like that will work in my specific case. Thank you! I am still curious, though, if there is a way to suppress the input if I wasn't using the variable for a PostgreSQL user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\password username
```

... will change the password for a given username, whilst suppressing the inputted password. I don't know of a way to do it for a given variable.